# Algorithm for teaching good vs. bad writing (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, corpus

One of my web apps receives a lot of article submissions, some of them written not very well. How possible is it to create a tool to recognize "good" vs. "bad" writing just by providing it with a corpora of good and bad articles?

Note that these articles (at least the ones already processed) have been reviewed and graded, so in theory I could use these numbers to confirm output.

I don't have a background in creating "learning" algorithms, so even just a pointer to a foundational book on the subject would be helpful, particularly one written for the Python language.

Comment: Natural Language is *very, very* complex. I doubt that any tool you could write without a large NLP library would be very good. Are there too many atricle submissions to read?

Comment: If such a tool existed that could discern good writing then software could potentially write a popular book.

Comment: We do have human reviewers, but it would be nice to filter out only the ones that are worth the reviewer's time. Also we have a digital library of around 50k+ articles, some of which are unscored because they come from diverse sources. If someone is trying to find papers related to a given subject, it would be useful to feature the best articles first.

Comment: I do know that there are, as we speak, computer programs out that score and evaluate student essays, particularly for large-scale tests with millions of test-takers. So it must have been done already in some fashion. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_essay_scoring

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for, but there's [the Flesch-Kincaid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests) readability test. (Some word processors used to implement this and similar other tests)

Comment: @suspectus, there are already computers who have made Bach music (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6HvDZcBMBk) and abstract art, so I'm guessing the written word is not too far behind...

Comment: @nvlass Interesting. Unfortunately, many of the poor writing is academics who are fully capable of putting together a sentence with many syllables but not much cohesive thought. :-\

Comment: @JordanReiter - _generating_ and _understanding_ something are two completely different beasts. Take [scigen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/) for example, writing a program that detects that these papers are nonsense is probably much more complicated then the algorithm that creates them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would be a difficult learning algorithm to undertake. However, if you did want to have a go or are just interested to learn about the subject Coursera offer a number of free online courses that are worth checking out.

This course is not currently running for assignments etc, but you can watch the lectures in preview mode, from what I have seen this is well suited to beginners:
https://class.coursera.org/machlearning-001/lecture/preview

If you want some practice then I would highly recommend taking a look at Kaggle (http://www.kaggle.com/) which runs open competitions for data science / machine learning problems. Some of the competitions even have sample code to get you started, the titanic competition has some sample code in Python, although the problem being worked on is considerably simpler than the problem you have proposed.

Comment: Have you considered submitting this problem to Kaggle as an open competition? Obviously, to do this you would need to be prepared to make the data public.